# Java treasure hunt game

Tags: java

I got a CA where i have to create a treasure hunt game and I cant figure out how to take the user input convert it to grid location and then display it with the user input in the grid. Can anyone give me some help? I just started learning java so i am very beginner so please bear with me lol. this is the code i been trying to use so far:

```
public void printBoard(){
    //*this method will actually print the board and fill it with the rows and columns labels 
    //and will be filled with the users' input: D if dug already or X if treasure been found

      board = new int [10][10];
      String[] nums = {"  1","  2","  3","  4","  5","  6","  7","  8","  9"," 10"};
     // char letters = 65;
      String[] letters = { "    A", "  B", "  C", "  D", "  E","  F", "  G", "  H", "  I", "  J"};
      for (int i = 0 ; i < board.length ; i++){

          System.out.print(letters[i]);
       //   letters++;
      }
      System.out.println("");

      for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { 
          System.out.print(nums[i]);

      for (int j = 0 ; j < board.length ; j++){

          if (board[i][j] == 0) { //empty index 
            System.out.print("__|");
        } else if (board[i][j] == 1){ //when user input wont be an empty index so print d|
              System.out.println("d|");
        } else if(board[i][j] == -1) { //-1 already filled position with the treasure location so print x|

              System.out.println("x|");

        } 

public void getUserInput(){

       int userRow, userColumn;

        do{
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter row");
            userRow = myScanner.nextInt() -1;
            System.out.println("Please enter column");
            userColumn = myScanner.nextInt() -1;

            if(board[userRow][userColumn] == -1){
                System.out.println("That square has been used. Pick again");
            }

        }while (board[userRow][userColumn] != 0);

        if ((board[userRow][userColumn]) == 1){
        }
        else{
            board[userRow][userColumn] = 1;
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're already converting the user input to the grid location? Where are you trying to display the grid, or the user input in the grid?

Comment: oh i have a printBoard();  to print the board again at the end of the getUserInput method just forgot to paste it. But still does not work.

Comment: Does not work? What does happen? What do you expect to happen? I suggest you check out the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).